# Adjust content on by default Opened Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have two drawers on left and on right. Now right drawer is in the lock-closed state, but left drawer can be open and close. On opening drawer, I am pushing the middle content using drawer offset. Now I also want right drawer (which is opened by default) should move/adjust the content also but I am unable to do it. Because when the left drawer is opened it pushes the content under the right drawer. So what I want the right drawer on default opening should adjust the content and when I open left drawer content should adjust and should not move under the right drawer.

**Here is my code:**

```
<DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_screen"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/bg">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/includedView"
                layout="@layout/view" />

        </RelativeLayout>


        <!--  ======= side menu ====== -->
        <RelativeLayout

            android:id="@+id/leftMenu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left">

            <include
                layout="@layout/leftmenuLayout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout

            android:id="@+id/rightMenu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="right">

            <include
                layout="@layout/rightmenuLayout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </RelativeLayout>
        <!-- ======================= -->
    </DrawerLayout>
```

**DrawerAcivity:**

```
 mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
  mDrawerLayout.setScrimColor(Color.parseColor("#00000000"));


        main_screen = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_screen);


        leftMenu= (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.leftMenu);

        rightMenu= (RelativeLayout) 
        findViewById(R.id.rightMenu);

        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);

        mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(new CustomDrawerLayout.DrawerListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                float moveFactor = 0;
                moveFactor = (drawerView.getWidth() * slideOffset);
                main_screen.setTranslationX(moveFactor);

            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {

            }
        });

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED, rightMenu);
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.END);


        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED, leftMenu);


        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = leftMenu.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = (((size.x / 2) / 4));
        rl_slider_menu.setLayoutParams(params);

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams paramsRight = 
        rightMenu.getLayoutParams();
        paramsRight.width = ((size.x / 3));
        rightMenu.setLayoutParams(paramsRight);

        DrawerLayout.LayoutParams paramsContent = (DrawerLayout.LayoutParams) main_screen.getLayoutParams();
        paramsContent.setMargins(0, 0, (((size.x / 2) / 4)), 0); //substitute parameters for left, top, right, bottom
        main_screen.setLayoutParams(paramsContent);
        main_screen.invalidate();
```

Comment: You should not push the content anywhere. The navigation drawer should cover the content when it's opened as the material design guideline describe it https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/navigation-drawer.html

Comment: Actually I doing that due to my requirement and the requirement is that the left drawer should push/adjust the content form left and right side both.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you want to happen, here. Are you saying when both drawers are open, the content should shrink, or be squeezed?

Comment: yes content should shrink/adjust from both sides on drawers opening and then adjust to its previous state on drawers closing

Comment: In the vertical direction, as well? I mean, like the whole content gets scaled down?

Comment: No from left and from right side

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not quite clear. Will both drawers ever be open at the same time? Or do you mean you're just trying to get this to work on both sides, one at a time?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166089/discussion-between-user42590-and-mike-m).

Comment: I see. I don't remember exactly if this had a right drawer too or not, but might be what you need. https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

Comment: I just posted some test code in the chat room, in case you didn't see.

Comment: Yes got it  and testing thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This actually turns out to be a pretty simple implementation, once you get your head wrapped around it.

We simply need to keep track of both drawers' inset measures, scale the content `View` to the remaining space, and then translate it by the difference of half of each inset. For example. building on the code in the question:

```
mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(new DrawerLayout.DrawerListener() {
        private float leftInset, rightInset;

        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
            if (drawerView == leftMenu) {
                leftInset = slideOffset * leftMenu.getWidth();
            }
            else {
                rightInset = slideOffset * rightMenu.getWidth();
            }

            final float scale = 1 - (leftInset + rightInset) / main_screen.getWidth();
            main_screen.setScaleX(scale);

            final float translation = leftInset / 2 - rightInset / 2;
            main_screen.setTranslationX(translation);
        }

        ...
}
```